# Por que as informações do EditTexts somem quando troco de activity?

Tags: android, edittext

Tenho um problema no qual as informações como "nome", "endereço" e "telefone" que digito dentro dos `EditText` da `Activity` principal somem quando vou para outra `Activity` buscar outros tipos de informações e volto para a principal que contem os `EditText`.

Já tentei usar esta configuração:

```
... android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
```

Mesmo assim os dados da `Activity` principal somem.
Por que isto ocorre e como posso resolve-lo?

`Activity` principal:

```
public class ServicoDeEmailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Session session = null;
    ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
    Context context = null;
    String rec;
    String subject;
    String textMessage;
    EditText editTextValorDoPedido;
    TextView txtValorTotalDoPedido;
    double valorDoPedido;
    int dados;
    String nomeDoProduto;
    String descricaoDoProduto;
    int quantidadeDoProduto;
    double precoUnitarioDoProduto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_servico_de_email);

        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

        context = this;

        final EditText nome;
        final EditText rua;
        final EditText numero;
        final EditText complemento;
        final EditText bairro;

        App app = (App) getApplicationContext();
        ItemCompra itemCompra = new ItemCompra();

        Log.i("ServicoDeEmailActivity", "Entrou no metodo onCreate()");

        final EditText telefone1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefone1);
        telefone1.addTextChangedListener(Mask
                .insert("(##)####-####", telefone1));

        final EditText telefone2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefone2);
        telefone2.addTextChangedListener(Mask
                .insert("(##)####-####", telefone2));

        final EditText cep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cep);

        cep.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("#####-###", cep));

        Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoIrParaProdutos);

        botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("ServicoDeEmailActivity", "Passou pelo metodo onClick()");
                Log.i("ServicoDeEmailActivity", "Chamando Lista de produtos");
                Intent irParaListaDeProdutos = new Intent();
                irParaListaDeProdutos.setClass(ServicoDeEmailActivity.this,
                        ProdutoActivity.class);

                startActivity(irParaListaDeProdutos);
                Log.i("ServicoDeEmailActivity", "Lista de produtos chamada!");
            }
        });

        nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);
        rua = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rua);
        numero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numero);
        complemento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.complemento);
        bairro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bairro);

        Intent intentRecuperaDadosDaLista = getIntent();
        Bundle parametroDadosDaLista = intentRecuperaDadosDaLista.getExtras();

        if (parametroDadosDaLista != null) {
            nomeDoProduto = parametroDadosDaLista.getString("nomeDoProduto");
            descricaoDoProduto = parametroDadosDaLista.getString("descricaoDoProduto");
            precoUnitarioDoProduto = parametroDadosDaLista.getDouble("precoUnitarioDoProduto");
            quantidadeDoProduto = parametroDadosDaLista.getInt("quantidadeDoProduto");
        }

        Button btnEnviarPedidoParaEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoEnviaPedido);

        btnEnviarPedidoParaEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                rec = "DIGITE O EMAIL DE QUEM IRÁ RECEBE-LO";
                subject = "Pedido Solicitado";
                textMessage = "Nome: " + nome.getText()
                        + "<br />" + "Rua: " + rua.getText()
                        + "<br />" + "Número: " + numero.getText()
                        + "<br />" + "Complemento: " + complemento.getText()
                        + "<br />" + "Bairro: " + bairro.getText()
                        + "<br />" + "CEP: " + cep.getText()
                        + "<br />" + "Telefone: " + telefone1.getText()
                        + "<br />" + "Celular: " + telefone2.getText()
                        + "<br />" + "Valor total do Pedido: " + CurrencyUtils.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(valorDoPedido))
                        + "<br />" + "-------------------------------"
                        + "<br />" + "Lista de itens solicitados:"
                        + "<br />" + "Produto: " + nomeDoProduto
                        + "<br />" + "Descrição :" + descricaoDoProduto
                        + "<br />" + "Preço unitário: " + CurrencyUtils.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(precoUnitarioDoProduto))
                        + "<br />" + "Quantidade :" + quantidadeDoProduto;

                Properties props = new Properties();

                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("DIGITE O EMAIL AQUI", "DIGITE A SENHA AQUI");
                    }
                });

                pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Enviando o pedido para o email...", true);

                RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
                task.execute();

            }

            class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    try {
                        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("cireas31@gmail.com"));
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(rec));
                        message.setSubject(subject);
                        message.setContent(textMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

                        Transport.send(message);
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    pdialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pedido enviado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });

        txtValorTotalDoPedido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_valor_total);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle params = intent.getExtras();
        if (params != null) {
            this.valorDoPedido = params.getDouble("ValorDoProduto");
            txtValorTotalDoPedido.setText(CurrencyUtils.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(valorDoPedido)));
        }

    }
}
```

E o *layout*:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTodo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewProdutos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/nome_" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/rua_" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/rua"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/n_mero_" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numero"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/complemento_" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/complemento"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/bairro_" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bairro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/cep_" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/telefone_1_" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/telefone1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="phone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/telefone_2_" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/telefone2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="phone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/botaoIrParaProdutos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lista de Produtos" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/total_r_" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_valor_total"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botaoEnviaPedido"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enviar Pedido" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Em alguma altura você altera a orientação do *Device*

Comment: Não ramaral, ainda não alterei a orientação

Comment: Em principio isso só deveria acontecer se houvesse uma mudança de orientação do *device* ou o Android destruísse a sua *Activity*. Tentei perceber o seu código mas ele está muito confuso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, consegui resolver o problema.

Estou utilizando na Activity principal os métodos startActivityForResult() e no final da activity onActivityResult(), tratando oque eu preciso como retorno.

Já na segunda activity, criei uma intent passando os valores que eu precisava, por fim passando setResult(RESULT_OK, intent) e finish();

Oque estava ocorrendo, é que nesta segunda Activity eu estava utilizando startActivity() para chamar a primeira activity, só que eu perdia os valores dos EditTexts porque o startActivity() estava estanciando uma nova Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Por algum motivo a sua Activity deve estar sendo destruída e possivelmente o método **onCreate()** está sendo chamado novamente, para recriar a sua Activity novamente. Isso ocorre quando o smartphone precisa de memória, talvez a sua ourta activity seja "pesada" e o aparelho demande mais memória, nessa caso ele precisa desalocar.

Observe o código abaixo, o valor **android:launchMode="singleTop"** talvez o ajude.

A linha deve ser inserida no arquivo **AndroidManifest.xml**, veja um exemplo.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Referência:
[manifest/activity-element.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Isto irá apenas "tentar contornar o problema"! E não sei se resolverá, se de facto, for um problema de memória

Comment: Nesse caso ainda não deu certo e o que tenho na outra activity são só 3 itens de uma lista onde uso ViewHolder que busco os valores dos produtos selecionados vezes os valores. Acredito que não exija tanta memória assim

Answer (score 0):

A minha resposta é direcionada ao **restauramento das informações** com:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
   super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
}

.....
```

No **EditText**

```
android:saveEnabled="true"
```

**EXEMPLO:**

```
package com.example.statechange;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class StateChangeActivity extends Activity {
.
.
.
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");

        final EditText textBox = 
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        CharSequence userText = textBox.getText();
        outState.putCharSequence("savedText", userText);

    }
.
.
.
```

**RESTAURANDO:**

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {      
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");

        final EditText textBox = 
               (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        CharSequence userText = 
               savedState.getCharSequence("savedText");

        textBox.setText(userText);
    }
```

*fonte:* 
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Saving_and_Restoring_the_User_Interface_State_of_an_Android_Activity

Comment: Interessante, embora a minha activity seja muito grande, acho que eu precisaria chamar o método onCreate(), correto?